# Passing a parameter to onClick function NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, next.js, package

I'm currently using the package [react-simple-star-rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-star-rating) with this example. But here's my problem :

My **trains** parameter contain a variable **id** I'd like to pass to the *handleRating* function using *onClick* but I can't figure it how.

```
const handleRating = (rate) => {
    console.log(rate)
}

const trainingLine = (trains) => (
    <Rating onClick={handleRating} ratingValue={Math.round(trains.rate.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0)/trains.rate.length)}/>
)
```

Do you have an idea to achieve that ?

Comment: Do you mean something like `<Rating onClick={() => handleRating(id)} ...` ?

Comment: @GabrielPichot Yes something like `<Rating onClick={() => handleRating(rate, id)}` but rate goes 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the solution well I think I missed something but in order to pass **rating** and **trains.id** variables to the *handleRating* function, I just need to to do this :

```
const handleRating = (rating, id) => {
    // Do something
}

<Rating onClick={(rating) => handleRating(rating, trains._id)} ratingValue={Math.round(trains.rate.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0)/trains.rate.length)}/>
```

Lot of struggle for something pretty understandable, I need some more practice ! Thank you guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your handleRating function as

```
    const handleRating = useCallback(
    (raiting: any) => (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        // do something
    },
    [...deps]);
```